# Running SpringBoot 3 application with Security Configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, repository, hibernate-entitymanager

I upgraded the application I have from java 8 to java 17, and springboot 3. and the app stopped running.
I have one repo:

I used ListCrudRepository instead of PagingAndSortingRepository which is not used in the current springboot version

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends ListCrudRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
    Optional<User> findByUsernameAndLkpUserType(String username, LkpUserType lkpUserType);
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
    Optional<User> findByRid(Long rid);
    
    Page<User> findAllByLkpUserType(LkpUserType lkpUserType, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Below you can find the full stack when i try to run the app.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 
2023-Aug-14 21:58:35 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication                            - Application run failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Receiver class org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.RevisionTypeType does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract int getSqlType()' of interface org.hibernate.usertype.UserType.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1155) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) [spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at com.healthcare.thelab.ThelabApplication.main(ThelabApplication.java:21) [classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
```

I reviewed all the recommanded dependencies but nothing is working.

Comment: can you share pom.xml file or gradle build file ? Just update the question with details

Comment: Looks like a dependency conflict to me.